# Удаление сделки amoCRM

Tags: php, crm

как можно удалить сделку в amoCRM API для PHP?

Comment: ИМХО, это вопрос для службы поддержки этого ресурса, а не SO - гляньте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Да, вот только поддержки API я не нашел, а на самом ресурсе мне сказали, что они решают технические проблемы работы системы, а другие вопросы не к ним. И куда мне идти в таком случае?

Answer (score 0):

Для удаления сделки необходимо

1 залогиниться как веб клиент `https://www.amocrm.ru/oauth2/authorize`

2 получить `csrf_token`

3 использовать метод удаления для клиента
`https://' . $this->domain . '.amocrm.ru/ajax/contacts/multiple/delete/`

с параметрами

```
http_build_query(
  [
    'ACTION' => 'DELETE', 
    'ID' => $ids
  ]
)
```